# What is the order of the element $a^2$ in the multiplicative group $G = \{a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5, a^6=e\}$?

Tags: group-theory, set-theory

What is the order of the element $a^2$ in the multiplicative group $G = \{a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5, a^6=e\}$?

Comment: What do you think?  Note:  it could be $1$.  Perhaps all these elements are equal to the identity.  Presumably, you intended to exclude that but that requires extra assumptions.

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score -1):

3, or 1, since $(a^2)^3 = a^6 = e$, and since if $a = e$, the order is 1.